# acess static files placed in WEB-INF

Tags: security, jsp, servlets

My requirement is to secure static files so that it cannot be accessed from url.I placed those css and js files inside WEB-INF but now i am not being able to access it from my jsp page.I tried following.

```
 webpages|
     WEB-INF|
       img|
          batman.jpg
 test.jsp
```

now i tried it to acess from jsp page as `<img src="../WEB-INF/img/batman.jpg"/>` as well as

```
<img src="img/batman.jpg"/>
```

but none works.test.jsp is placed outside of web-inf and placing it inside of web-inf is currently not an option for me.I am not using Spring Framework just basic jsp and servlet and i want solution for them.Thnks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EJP rightfully stated, if you want to embed an image in your page you are bound to access it via an URL. Think of it like that: even though you manage to restrict access to image source (though you won't be able to), user will be able to copy it off the screen, which violates your assumption and which is left *to the client*.

But of course there are some workarounds to achieve 'second-best' functionality to your problem. I'll list some of them that come to mind:

1. **Put a watermark**. Place your images in public folders, but modify the content by providing a watermark to every sensible image. This way you don't restrict the access, but lower the probability of fraudulent behavior after images' exposure;
2. **Modify filenames**. You could modify filenames of your images and keep correspondence between 'real' name and artificial name on the server, for example, in a database. This way you'll significantly lower the risk of mass leakage of secured images;
3. **Introduce client side restrictions**. You can introduce client side restrictions on your image elements, like disallowing appearance of popup menus, showing full images in dialogs that force user into thinking that image is protected, etc. Of course, anyone with little browser experience will be able to get the content, but basic users won't.

I think that there are many more ways to lower the probability of inappropriate behaviour, but none of these ways reduce that probability to zero. So, you're basically left with opening access to your images, while you may make malicious work harder by putting a watermark on all of your sensible images.

Comment: thnks for the clarfication but i want css and js files to be secure.Yeah they both can be viewed from firebug or other tools but the comments that i have kept in those files are not visible then but if they acess it by url then they will be able to see those comments as well.

Comment: You can of course secure all your resource files and 'clean' them in a servlet. But it is a rather error-prone approach and you'd be better off having one file for development (the one with your comments) and one file for production (clean). It'd be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are mutually contradictory. You are making a resource inaccessible via a URL and then attempting to access it via a URL.

Make up your mind.

Comment: okay then what should be the approach.I dont want user to see my css and js files by directly giving its url.But it still should be accessed from my jsp pages.Please help

Comment: @ntstha If the browser can access them, so can the user directly. There is no difference between these two cases. What you are asking for embodies a contradiction in terms.